# How do I execute a wp_remote_get call using NTLM authentication?

Tags: authentication, wp-remote-get

I need to use ntlm authentication for a remote call, and I'm not sure how to configure the wp_remote_get call to do so. I have used `wp_remote_get` successfully in other situations without NTLM by passing the appropriate header: `headers -> authentication -> basic u:p` but I haven't been able to find any information about using NTLM.

I tried changing 'Basic' to 'NTLM' but it didn't work. Wishful thinking I guess!

Comment: I had a project involving NTLM recently, but it was a SOAP API? Is yours too? Will probably affect the approach.

Comment: No, mine is just making an api call to a Teamspace site (ugh). Actually, I'm not sure if it's a SOAP api at all. All I know is that I can do the curl call via the CMD line and it works with the --ntlm parameter. I can do the call with jQuery, but that only works in IE (another ugh). So server side is better. I have it working with an explicit curl call, but would like to try to use WordPress's wrappers.

Comment: @Jason did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @JacobPeattie what was your outcome on this? falling into a NTLM API nightmare at the moment!

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv My issue was accessing a SOAP API with NTLM, so it was pretty specific to SOAP. I ended up having to use these 2 classes: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php/

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv I ended up using curl and I believe I was able to specify ntlm in there. I will find the code tomorrow on my work computer and verify.

Comment: @Jason and JacobPeattie I ended up finding this link after some research: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31232#comment:7 which I know is 4 years old but added that code and BOOM instant connection.